# Hash giving null value for a key which exists in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following code -

```
def check_org_exists(org_name)
        res = self.class.get('/organizations/search', {query: {term: org_name, exact_match: true, api_token: ENV["PIPEDRIVE_API_TOKEN"]}})
        if res[:success] or res['success']
            return {'success': true, 'org_exists': !res['data']['items'].empty?, 'org': res['data']['items'][0]}
        else
            return {'success': false, 'error': res['error']}
        end
    end
res = check_org_exists(profile_params['businessName'])
        if res[:success] or res['success']
            puts "###"*20
            puts "#{res}"
            org_exists = res['org_exists'] or res[:org_exists]
            org = res['org'] or res[:org]
            puts "*&&"*30
            puts "#{org_exists}"
            puts "#{org}"
```

And I am getting following output

```
############################################################
{:success=>true, :org_exists=>true, :org=>{"result_score"=>0.45958003, "item"=>{"id"=>6035, "type"=>"organization", "name"=>"BeautifulCode Test", "address"=>nil, "visible_to"=>1, "owner"=>{"id"=>9055471}, "custom_fields"=>["BeautifulCode Test", "BeautifulCode Test", "BeautifulCode Test"], "notes"=>[]}}}
*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&*&&
```

Last 2 statements are evaluating to null. Can anyone explain me why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here has to do with operator precedence in Ruby. From [this table](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4), we can see that the `||` (logical OR) has higher precedence that `=` (assignment), which has higher precedence than `or` (logical composition).

Let's look at this line.

```rb
org_exists = res['org_exists'] or res[:org_exists]
```

Because of the operator precedence rules, the assignment (`=`) will take precedence over the logical composition (`or`). With brackets to emphasize precedence, this is equivalent to the following.

```rb
(org_exists = res['org_exists']) or res[:org_exists]
```

The whole statement will produce `true`, but the assignment will cause `org_exists` to be assigned to `nil`. Replace the `or` with `||` in order to prioritize the logical ORing, and that will assigns `org_exists` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Assignment has a higher precedence than `or`. Use `||` instead:

```
a = nil or 1
pp a
=> nil

a = nil || 1
pp a
=> 1
```

So:

```
# This ....
a = nil or 1

# Actually equals this
(a = nil) or 1

# While this ...
a = nil || 1

# Equals this
a = (nil || 1)
```